# How to use c++11/14 to simplify this implementation

Tags: c++, c++11

Story is a little long, it is a endian universal implementation for integer, original code is like as:

```
#ifdef _BIG_ENDIAN_
#define ENDIANUSHORT(src)       (unsigned short)src
#define ENDIANULONG(src)        (unsigned long)src
#define ENDIANUINT64(src)       (unsigned long long)src
#else
#define ENDIANUSHORT(src)       ((unsigned short)((((src)>>8)&0xff) |\
                                                (((src)<<8)&0xff00)))

#define ENDIANULONG(src)        ((unsigned long)((((src)>>24)&0xFF) |\
                                                (((src)>> 8)&0xFF00) |\
                                                (((src)<< 8)&0xFF0000) |\
                                                (((src)<<24)&0xFF000000)))

#define ENDIANUINT64(src)       ((unsigned long long)((((src)>>56)&0xFF) |\
                                                (((src)>>40)&0xFF00) |\
                                                (((src)>>24)&0xFF0000) |\
                                                (((src)>> 8)&0xFF000000) |\
                                                (((src)<< 8)&0xFF00000000LL) |\
                                                (((src)<<24)&0xFF0000000000LL) |\
                                                (((src)<<40)&0xFF000000000000LL) |\
                                                (((src)<<56)&0xFF00000000000000LL)))
#endif //_BIG_ENDIAN_

template<
    typename T, 
    typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer>::type* = nullptr>
T _endian(T& t) {
if (sizeof(T) == 2)
    return ENDIANUSHORT(t);
else if (sizeof(T) == 4)
    return ENDIANULONG(t);
else if (sizeof(T) == 8)
    return ENDIANUINT64(t);

return t;
}

template<typename T>
void endian(T& t) { t = _endian(t); }

int main()
{   
    long lv = 123;
    endian(lv);
    ......
}
```

It works well, but there are warnings in MSVC like as:

```
warning C4293: '>>': shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior
```

Then refined it as:
Replace T _endian(T& t) define with the below code:

```
static int64_t _endian(int64_t t) {
    return ENDIANUINT64(t);
}

static uint64_t _endian(uint64_t t) {
    return ENDIANUINT64(t);
}

static int32_t _endian(int32_t t) {
    return ENDIANULONG(t);
}

static uint32_t _endian(uint32_t t) {
    return ENDIANULONG(t);
}

static int16_t _endian(int16_t t) {
    return ENDIANUSHORT(t);
}

static uint16_t _endian(uint16_t t) {
    return ENDIANUSHORT(t);
}

static int8_t _endian(int8_t t) {
    return t;
}

static uint8_t _endian(uint8_t t) {
    return t;
}
```

Now no warning, but I think there are 2 disadvantages:

1. The functions implementation is dull, redundant and inconcise.
2. Maybe some cases are not covered

I think C++11/14 can provide an elegant and short implementation to finish it, have you any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to have a look into the boost endianess library.

Comment: Thanks for your information. boost is very famous, but from my point view, I don't want to introduce additional huge code base implementation, so I am not the fans of boost.

Comment: I am also no fan of introducing a lot of unneccessary code. Just have a look what they did ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need c++11/14 per se. What you need to do is

1. Replace those macros with inline functions. That's not only more c++sy, it also facilitates the next step.
2. Make said inline functions be `static constexpr` members in a traits
   class. Accepting `size_t` of the integer as template parameter.
3. Implement the template in terms of the traits class.

The code:

```
template<std::size_t> struct EndianTraits;

template<>
struct EndianTraits<2u>
{
  using type = std::uint16_t;
#ifdef _BIG_ENDIAN_
  constexpr static type ToEndian(type val) { return val; }
#else
  constexpr static type ToEndian(type val) { return ((((val)>>8)&0xff) |
                                                    (((val)<<8)&0xff00))); }
#endif
};

template<typename T, 
         typename = std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer>::type>
T Endian(T t) {
  using type = EndianTraits<sizeof(T)>::type;
  return EndianTraits<sizeof(T)>::ToEndian(static_cast<type>(t));
}
```

Comment: for #1 and #2, I can understand them, but they are not my focus, as for #3, I guess it may be a good solution, can you show me some quick example?

Comment: @ravin.wang, added for short ints. But note that #1 & #2 are a must to do #3. Also, you shouldn't name stuff in the global scope with leading underscore. Those names are reserved for you implementation by the standard.

Comment: Teller Thanks for answer, it seems to solve my question. to be honest, I think the code is not so concise, because we have to define struct EndianTraits<2u>, struct EndianTraits<4u>, struct EndianTraits<8u>, struct EndianTraits<1u>,or struct EndianTraits<1>, struct EndianTraits<2>, struct EndianTraits<4>, struct EndianTraits<8>

Comment: @ravin.wang, you only need to define for unsiged values, since `size_t` is guaranteed unsigned. And Only up to `8u` as in your case. That's only three cases, which you have to define as it were with your current setup.

Comment: Yes, you are right, no wonder a signed unsigned long can be compiled successfully, it is ok to only implement 4 EndianTraits, great!

Comment: @ravin.wang, well I suppose it's *a bit* less convenient since you need to check for `_BIG_ENDIAN_` three times as opposed to one, but you trade that off for type safety.